# passar valor de um select para uma página php sem atualizar a página!

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, aplicação-web

Bom dia, pessoal eu tenho um evento de onchange em um select, eu queria pegar o valor do select e enviar para uma pagina php.

```
    $(document).on("change", "#doc_sel_clinic", function(){

  var id = $(this).val();
  $("#id_clinic_hidden").val(id);
    console.log(id);


});
```

eu preciso enviar esse id e pegar na página php para fazer uma busca pelos dados somente por esse id, uso o codeigniter com url amigavel.

eu tentei passar via sessão pra pegar com php e não consegui, quais alternativas para fazer isso?

obrigado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa fazer uma requisição assíncrona (mais conhecida popularmente como AJAX) para alcançar o que deseja.

Assumindo que você tenha uma página PHP que trate os dados que você enviar, você pode usar o jQuery e fazer algo assim:

```
$('#doc_sel_clinic').on('change', function() {
  var id = $(this).val()

  // Se fosse uma requisição POST, você pode trocar `$.get` por `$.post`:
  $.get('/tratar-dados.php', {
    // Você poderá acessar essa propriedade pelo PHP com `$_GET['id']`:
    id: id
  })
    .done(function(resposta) {
      alert('Dados salvos com sucesso!')

      // Resposta é a mensagem que o PHP "mandou" de volta ao cliente.
      // Supondo que na sua página PHP você tenha um `echo $_GET['id']`, a
      // resposta irá ser uma `string` com o ID que você passou no objeto
      // como segundo argumento na função `$.get`.
      alert('Resposta do servidor: ' + resposta)
    })
    .fail(function() {
      alert('Whoops! Parece que houve um erro ao tentar tratar os dados.')
    })
})
```

#### Referência:

- [`jQuery.get`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/).

Comment: "*o objetivo do site não é [...] dar o código pronto como ele pede nesse contexto*" - Vc ;)

Comment: Obrigado, fiz dessa forma que falou. recebi a mensagem de sucesso porém quando vou buscar no php ele só mostrar que está vazio. Dessa forma array(0) { }. Alguém sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: O que está vazio? O que você está tentando acessar?